# VBA - Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto

Tags: excel, vba

Vinculé un botón a un formulario para poder abrir el formulario una vez se haga click en el botón. Funciono bien la primera vez, pero ahora me da el siguiente error.

> Error definido por la aplicación o el objeto

Cuando elijo "depurar", muestra que el error se encuentra en la siguiente línea de código:

```
Set GetRange = GetRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetRange.Rows.Count - 1)
```

Estas líneas de código las utilizo para poder obtener el contenido de mi tabla y eliminar los títulos.

```
Public Function GetRange() As Range
    Set GetRange = Sheet1.Range("B5").CurrentRegion
    Set GetRange = GetRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetRange.Rows.Count - 1)
End Function
```

Al eliminar la línea de código `Set GetRange = GetRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetRange.Rows.Count - 1)` no obtengo error, sin embargo, en el menu se puede ver los títulos de la tabla. Hay alguna forma de utilizar un código que no muestre los títulos en el menu?

Esta es la tabla que estoy utilizando y el menu en donde se debe visualizar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0):

Utiliza F8 para depurar paso a paso. Aunque te muestra la línea **frmDaily.Show** como error casi con total seguridad es que el error lo tengas en el evento **UserForm_Initialize()**.

Con F8 vas ejecutando el código línea a línea y llegarás a un punto en el que el programa devuelva error de nuevo. Fíjate bien en qué línea de código se detiene la ejecución y vuelve a **frmDaily.Show**. Esa será la parte de código que tengas que revisar.

Para eliminar los títulos puedes hacerlo con una sóla línea de código:

```
Public Function GetRange() As Range
    Set GetRange = Sheet1.Range("B6").CurrentRegion
End Function
```

Así el rango de datos lo tomas desde la fila 6, sin los títulos.

Comment: Al depurar muestra el error en la línea de código `Set GetRange = GetRange.Offset(1).Resize(GetRange.Rows.Count - 1)` esto lo utilizo para eliminar los títulos de mi tabla. Si elimino la línea de código no hay error. Hay alguna forma diferente de eliminar los títulos?

Comment: En esta línea: **Set GetRange = Sheet1.Range("B5").CurrentRegion** estás indicando que tu rango comienza en la fila 5. Los títulos entiendo que están en esa fila, pon un 6 ahí y el rango no tomará la fila de los títulos. Así, tu segunda línea de código no te hará falta. Actualizo la respuesta.